# Compilation failure associated with vector of const std::string

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, stdvector

Please can someone explain why the following code doesn't compile using clang 3.5.

The error reported is 'No viable overloaded '=' in algorithm.'

```
std::vector<const std::string> m_messages;
std::vector<const std::string>::iterator iter;
...

if (iter != m_messages.end())
{
    m_messages.erase(iter);      // compilation error
}
```

If I declare `m_messages` as: `std::vector<std::string> m_messages;` then it compiles OK.

Also, what is the difference between:

```
std::vector<const std::string> m_messages;
```

and

```
std::vector<std::string> m_messages;
```

TIA.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To erase an element, the right hand side elements have to be relocated (shifted to the left).

Since your strings are `const`, the old element cannot be overwritten (via the `=` operator) hence the error.

Comment: Does that mean it makes no sense to have a vector of const strings if the elements can be removed?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I'm versed enough to confirm this, but with how vector is implemented, it seems so..  but it certainly makes sense to have a container that supports this (e.g. via destructor + copy constructor). maybe there's something in the boost library?

Comment: OK thanks. Maybe I'll as a separate question relating to that specifically if I don't get an answer here.

Comment: it depends where you are running with this code: I get compilation failure on gcc4.9.2 (https://ideone.com/muNr2g), but works okay on VS2013

Comment: The destructor + copy constructor combination has the problem that if the constructor throws you have a "hole" in the middle of the vector. Then what? Destroying that vector would result in double-destructing one element - UB! std::vector has to copy or move elements first, and destroy any elements at the end of an operation, to avoid creating such "holes".

Comment: If you really need non-copiable objects, (like `const`), use the node-based containers: `map` `set` `unordered_map` `unordered_set` `list` and `forward_list`.

Answer (score 5):

Does that mean it makes no sense to have a vector of const strings if the elements can be removed? `Yes at least what the standard says`

**23.3.7.5 vector modifiers [vector.modifiers]**

> iterator erase(const_iterator position); iterator erase(const_iterator
>   first, const_iterator last);
>
> **Effects**: Invalidates iterators and references at or after the point of the erase.
>
> **Complexity**: The destructor of T is called the number of times equal to the number of the elements erased, but the move assignment operator of T is called the number of times equal to the number of elements in the vector after the erased elements.
>
> **Throws**: Nothing unless an exception is thrown by the copy constructor, move constructor, assignment operator, or move assignment operator of T.